# Interact factor with treatment, setting different base level

Tags: r, radix, interaction

Trying to estimate `lm` with a factor variable for months. I want to include an interaction between this factor and a treatment variable (equals 1 for treatment group), as well as including just the factor. Something like:

```
lm(y ~ month + treatment:month, data = DF)
```

The thing is, I want to set the base level which will be omitted manually. To be specific, I want to set "2015-08-01" as the base level.

Tried `relevel(month, "2015-08-01")`, and it seems the order of levels have changed, with August 2015 now being first. The coefficient of month does omit August 2015, but for the interaction that is not the case. For the interaction I get the coefficient of August 2015, and I have the last month of the data being NA. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably because you have no main effect of treatment. Use `y ~ month *  treatment`?

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks!